# Can't access my server from within the network after changing ISPs (new router)

Tags: networking, router, dns, wireless-router

I have a small Django website which is hosted on a raspberry pi on my network and has been running smoothly for a few years. I recently changed my ISP from Comcast to Century Link. After the change, I discovered that my old router couldn't support the new speeds. So I decided to use Century Link's modem/router as my router (Zyxel C3000Z). Since then, I haven't been able to connect to my site from within my network.

I have updated my domain to point to my new IP address and I have forwarded the correct ports on the router.

If I am outside of my network, I can confirm that my server is receiving requests when I hit my domain. So I know that my port forwarding is set up correctly. However, I am using SSL so when I hit my site from outside of the network, the login page loads, but then it hangs and is unable to connect when I submit the login request. I assume this is because its trying to redirect to itself after authenticating and can't connect to itself within the network. If I hit the domain inside of the network the browser says it can't connect.

I'm sure this is just a configuration in the router. This router has a lot more configuration options than my old one. Are there some common router settings that I should check that might cover a scenario like this?

Edit:
The Django error page when it eventually times out says `ConnectionError at /`

Comment: Doesn't seem like a network or SSL problem; if you can load the login page then both must be working. Did you ever hard code something on your website? For example, did your internal IP addresses change and is the old IP address of your database punched into the web server? What do you mean by 'redirect to itself after authenticating'?

Comment: There shouldn't be anything hard-coded. I've reviewed all of the apache settings and the Django app settings to make sure there weren't any references that might be causing this issue. I'm making an assumption that once I click 'Login', the server redirects to the homepage and that's the issue, but that may be a bad assumption.

Comment: The homepage is still the same website on the same webserver with the same SSL cert, right?

Comment: Yes its all the same server. Again this was all working just fine with my old router. I don't understand how switching a router could cause any issue unless it is a router configuration issue.

Comment: I'm stumped. Sorry. I know nothing about django, but if you start hunting down that error, do you find something useful? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516443/ Cross post your question to django and maybe they can help more.

Comment: If you have changed nothing in your network except the router, then the problem is with it. We need more information about its settings to have an opinion. Try to compare the settings pages of both old & new routers to find the difference.

Comment: My old router has a lot fewer settings than the new one from CL. I thought this might be a common issue (not being able to access domain from within network of server hosting domain). I will fire up the old router and try to compare settings again. I've done a lot of searching on the error itself as it relates to Django, but haven't found anything helpful. I may still crosspost to see if someone can help. I wish I could provide more, but I'm less experienced on the networking side of things.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but only after almost 2 years with the same router. From any device connected to it, I can't use an external IP address to access my server which is also connected to the router. This has only started happening in the past week, so I must've gotten some auto-update to the firmware that broke mine, the way yours started out broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After speaking with some people with experience with Centurylink in similar scenarios and doing a lot of research online, I've concluded that this is caused by a limitation of some kind in the C3000Z modem/router.

I've since purchased an ASUS RT-AC68U for my routing and set the C3000Z up in transparent bridge mode only. This immediately resolved all of my issues connecting to my sever from within the network.

I highly recommend the above router so far.